# Need Help Understanding Example of Integer Sequence A007178

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, integers

I am trying to understand the following integer sequence because it is related to a project of mine:
https://oeis.org/A007178

The sequence is defined as "[The] number of ways to write 1 as ordered sum of n powers of 1/2, allowing repeats." My issue with this definition is, if I'm not misunderstanding it, it is too broad. I can interpret it two ways: either the number of ways to write 1 using sums of (1/2)^n or the number of ways to write 1 using *n different* powers of (1/2). Neither of these are correct as the example for n = 3 is (1/2 + 1/4 + 1/4), (1/4 + 1/2 + 1/4), and (1/4, 1/4, 1/2).

I cannot extrapolate what the permutations for a higher n would like just from this information. Should the sums contain every power of 1/2 up to n? Consider n = 4, the sum

(1/2) + (1/4) + (1/8) + (1/8) can be permuted 4!/2!, or 12 ways.

The sum (1/2) + (1/8) + (1/8) + (1/8) + (1/8) can be permuted 5!/4!, or 5 ways.

I have just listed 17 ordered sums of n powers that equal 1, but the sequence says it should be 13.

Can someone write out what n = 4 would look like?

Comment: Not sure I see the problem.  I would read it as looking for the ordered sum of $n$ terms, each a power of $\frac 12$. You get $a_3=3$ which is what they give as well.

Comment: You could also use (1/4)+(1/4)+(1/4)+(1/4)=1 as well surely?

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks lulu and stuart.

Comment: No problem.  Good luck.

Comment: From the sequence definition you gave, your second interpretation is incorrect. Because repeats are allowed, they don't  have to be different powers of (1/2). If you adjust that 2nd interpretation to allow repeats of a particular power of n, that should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence counts the number of ways to count sums of n powers of 1/2, as in there are n terms in the sum. Thus, a4 would have all permutations of {1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/8} as well as {1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4}.

Thanks to lulu and stuart stevenson for clarification.